# How to check for empty values with in_array WITH EXCEPTIONS?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figue out how to check for empty values of an array with certain exceptions. Here is the array:

```
[name_first] => Name
[name_last] => 
[email] => blah@blah.com
[address] => 
[country] => USA
```

There are two empty values - `name_last` & `address`. Here is the code:

```
if (in_array(null, $data)) {
   echo 'empty values';
  }else{
     echo 'ok'; 
  }
```

It will return `false` as `[address]` and `[name_last]` values are `empty`. How can I ignore a particular key (let's say  -  `[address]`)? Basically it is supposed to LOOK like this:

```
if (in_array(null, $data) **&& key_is_not('address', 'hatever')**) {
   echo 'empty values';
  }else{
     echo 'ok'; 
  }
```

Comment: if  it's a particular `index` why not just unset the keys first then bring them back again after the checking?

Comment: what is ineed is this: to send db request to get all fields for a prticular user.
let's say there are plenty of fields (50). I need nearly all of them checked and confirmed those are not empty. but NOT all of them. about 3-5 keys are not needed to be checked BUT are needed to be returned on teh page (even if those are empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$data = array('name_first' => "Name",
'name_last' => "",
'email' => "blah@blah.com",
'address' => "",
'country' => "USA");


foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if($value=="")
    echo "$key is Empty\n";
}
```

**Update**

To exclude particular keys from the check, you can do this way :

```
$data = array('name_first' => "",
'name_last' => "",
'email' => "blah@blah.com",
'address' => "",
'country' => "");

$array = array("name_first","country");
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if($value=="" and (!in_array($key, $array)))
    echo "$key is Empty\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code will show which keys have empty values. But I need to exclude , let's say , 'address' from checking.  just imagine I have 50 elements inside the array. but I want to make sure only 48 are not empty but TWO particular ones I do not care about so I'd like to exclude those from the check.

Comment: Do you know those particular keys ?

Answer (score 1):

This will check to see if the value is set and the length is greater than 0, not an empty string.

```
foreach($elements as $key => $data)
{
    if(!in_array($key, ['address', 'something']))
    {
        if(count($data) > 0)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know there are elements in the array. I just would like to EXCLUDE certain keys from checking. Please re-read my question.

Comment: just imagine I have 50 elements inside the array. but I want to make sure only 48 are not empty in and only TWO particular ones I do not care about so I'd like to exclude those from the check.

Comment: Are you looping through the elements or accessing them directly?

Comment: This array is a database query result. there are plenty of fields and I have to check that only some of thsoe are empty. Instead of writing a long if/else statement I'd liek to analyze the array and get keys that have empty values. BUT - with some exceptions (please check my decsription again). Thanks buddy!

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain your question better, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_array = [
    'name_first' => 'Name',
    'name_last' => '',
    'email' => 'blah@blah.com',
    'address' => '',
    'country' => 'USA',
    ];
```

Filter array ignoring the specific keys, here `address` and `name_last`

```
$ignore_search = in_array('', array_filter($input_array, function($k){
        return !in_array($k, ['address', 'name_last']);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Here `array_filter` will unset the keys specified inside.

Will return boolean depending on match found or not, if you want keys, just change `in_array` with `array_search`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also ignore the key by writing a custom function that will handle the keys exception, this way you are more in control if in any case you want to tweak later:

```
if (in_array_except(null, $data, array("address"))) {
    echo 'empty values';
}else{
    echo 'ok';
}
```

The function will be:

```
function in_array_except($needle, $haystack, $exception = array(), $strict = false) {
    if ($strict) {
        foreach($haystack as $needle_field => $item) {
            if (!in_array($needle_field, $exception) && $item === $needle) 
                    return true; 
        }
    } else {
        foreach($haystack as $needle_field => $item) {
            if (!in_array($needle_field, $exception) && $item == $needle) 
                    return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With your current data set:

```
[name_first] => Name
[name_last] => 
[email] => blah@blah.com
[address] => 
[country] => USA
```

The output with the sample snippet is:

```
empty values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_search()` like below::

```
if (array_search("", $arr)) {
    echo 'empty values';
} else {
    echo 'ok'; 
}
```

** Update **

```
$array_var = array("11" => 111, "22" => 222, "33" => 333, "44" => 444, "55" => "", "66" => 666);
$new_array_var = array();

foreach ($array_var as $key => $value) {
//  echo $key . "==>" . $value . "<br/>";
    if (isset($value) && $value != "") {
        $new_array_var[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";

echo "OLD : <br/>";
print_r($array_var);

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo "NEW : <br/>";
print_r($new_array_var);

echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: but it won't do what I need, Kausha
this will do pretty much teh same whil I need to IGNORE certain keys or teh array from checking

Comment: @Rossitten ohhhh, then you can use loop and check each element whatever you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ignore_array = array("address");
$blank_value_keys = array_keys($data,"");
if(sizeof($blank_value_keys)>0 && sizeof(array_diff($ignore_array,$blank_value_keys)>0){
     echo "Empty";
}else{
     echo "NOT Empty";
}
```

Add all the keys to be ignored in ignore array list.
`array_keys` will return all the keys which have blank values.
Next we are checking if size of array returned by array_keys is greater than 0 and there are more keys in `$blank_value_keys` than `$ignore_array` than if loop executes.
**Note:** `array_diff` will return all the values available in second array but not in first

Comment: While this code snippet might answer the question. Please try to explain the code with relevant information. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer